# 32 bits into unit64 conversion in C++

Tags: c++, memcpy

I want to put a 32 bit value into unsigned int. I want this program to run on platfroms with 32 and 64 bit int too and with both little and big endians. Here is my code

```
  void uCHarToInt(unsigned char* input, unsigned int* oputput)
  {
       memcpy(oputput, reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&input), 4);

      if (sizeof(unsigned int) == 8) 
      {
           *oputput >>= 32;
      }
  }
```

I think this is going to work with big endnian and with 32 and 64 bit integer types, but I am not sure about little endian and how does memcpy behave on different platforms. Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Why do you think you need reinterpret cast here? Why don't you simply use `uint32_t`, which is guaranteed to have the exact size you want?

Comment: I reused some old code and ID give me advice to use this cast.. and  I have functions, that returns unsigned ints, but it seems better to change them... so this will work on all platforms yes? 
void uCHarToInt(unsigned char* input, uint32_t* oputput)
{
 memcpy(oputput, input, 4);
}

Comment: Forget about the code. Describe what you want to achieve, without any mentioning of how you attempt to achieve it. Because plainly, the code is weird to say the least.

Comment: @gnasher729 I want to store the sequence of next 32 bits from input into variable, so i can work with it as number, and I want the code to be as robust as possible.. so i get the same number on different platforms

Comment: @RainMaker but some sequence of 32 bits can represent a multitude of numbers. What number do you want it to represent? What order are the bits in? Why use `memcpy`? Why not just shift the individual bytes into place?

Comment: I want to have positive integer between 0 and 2^32 - 1. I now see what i missed, sorry. The number should be counter for someting and it is at beggining of array of unsigned chars that i get from another function. In that function I store the variable into it. That is basically reverse operation, which I will implement based on this answer too, and i want to know what is the best way to do it. Simply i need store unsigned int of length 32 bits into array of unsigned chars and then retrieve it in another function.

Comment: Use a union containing a uint32_t, and char[4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't there a better solution?

There is indeed.

It's not clear from the question whether the sequence of bytes you are being given is little-endian or big-endian (I am assuming that they have arrived as part of a communications protocol?)

The following functions will perform the conversion correctly, regardless of the word size or endian-ness of the receiving host:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<class Iter>
unsigned int accumulate_value(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for( ; first != last ; ++first)
    {
        result <<= 8;
        result |= *first;
    }
    return result;

}

unsigned int from_big_endian_stream(const unsigned char* bytes, size_t size = 4)
{
    return accumulate_value(bytes, bytes + size);
}

unsigned int from_little_endian_stream(const unsigned char* bytes,
                                       size_t size = 4)
{
    return accumulate_value(std::make_reverse_iterator(bytes+4),
                            std::make_reverse_iterator(bytes));
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char little_endian_data[] = { 3, 0, 2, 0 };
    unsigned char big_endian_data[] = { 0, 2, 0, 3 };

    std::cout << std::hex << from_little_endian_stream(little_endian_data)
    << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::hex << from_big_endian_stream(big_endian_data)
    << std::endl;

}
```

expected results:

```
20003
20003
```